# calculate number of occurrences in array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to calculate the number of occurences of a specific number I decide in my main method. Here is what I have to do :

• A function that fills the array with random numbers.

• A function that calculates the number of occurrences,this function may not do any input or output.

• The main function that asks the user for the number and present the result on the screen.

Here is my code in java :

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code {

    public void calculate(int value) {

        Code c = new Code();
        int count=0;
        for (int n=0; n<array.length; n++) { // the code does not recognize array
            if (array[n]==value) { // the code does not recognize array
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }

    public void addToArray() {

        int k =0;
        int [] array = new int[10];
        int min=0;
        int max=10;
        int diff = max-min;
        while (k<10) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(diff);
        array[k]=x;
        k=k+1;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("give your number");
        Code c = new Code();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = s.nextInt();
        c.addToArray();
        c.calculate(value);



    }

}
```

The only thing I need help with is the calculate method ,, eclipse does not recognize array in the calculate method above ..

How to correct the calculate method to make it recognize array ?

thank you

Comment: Pass it to the method in a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array` is limited to the scope of the method `addToArray()`. So, it will not be visible to other methods. You need to make it global. Then it will work.

Instead of declaring array in the method `addToArray`, declare it in your class, like:

```
public class Code {
    int [] array = new int[10];
    ...
```

Comment: Or pass it into the method as a parameter.

Comment: @Thilo Yes you can. But when an object/variable is to be accessed by multiple methods of the same class, then I prefer to declare it as an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

if using Java 8 you could update your calculate methode like this :

```
      public void calculate(int value) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array)
                                     .filter(i -> i == value)
                                     .count());
      }
```

By adding this imports to your class :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

And like mentionned HackerDarshi declaring the attribut array as a member of your class